# Deploying printers in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, printing

To deploy printers in a XP/Server 2003 environment using GPO should I use:

```
User Configuration / Policies / Windows Settings / Deployed Printers
```

or

```
User Configuration / Policies / Preferences / Control Panel Settings / Printers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid Preferences like the plague. XP needs a special client for them to 'work' (in quotes because they rarely and inconsistently work). I've had nothing but problems with Preferences on WinXP especially, but also Vista, 7, and Server OSes.